# How do I check how much time remains before timer fires next event?

Tags: c#

For example, I have set `timer1.Interval` to `5000` and I would like to know how much of this interval remains before the timer ticks. How I can do it?

Comment: The `Interval` value is a double. So you're comparing a double with an int

Comment: It should be `<=` and not `=<` .

Comment: @Pieter888: no, `Interval` is in integer and indicates milliseconds...

Comment: @Marco this page tells me it's double though... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Pieter888 You can compare them, however at the edge values you might get fuzzy results (as it is always when comparing with doubles).

Comment: @Marco @-Pieter There are three different timer classes in .net. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has an integer interval in milliseconds, `System.Timers` has a double interval in milliseconds, and  `System.Threading.Timer` has no `Interval` property at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How to check timer time?

You cannot. The timer classes offer no way check how long remains before a timer is due to fire. The best you can do is to keep track of when the timer last fired and calculate yourself how long remains before the next tick.

Comment: Thanks. I can: timer1.Start(); and next count time by DateTime function. Am I right?

Comment: That's right. You have to make a note of the time every time the timer ticks, or when you start it. And then when you want to know how long before the next tick is due, read the time again and calculate how much time has elapsed. But the timer classes don't tell you this.

Comment: Ok. Thanks) Your advice was very useful. Sorry I can't plus it.

Comment: No problems. Accepting answers from old questions gives you a bit more rep, FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

```
        DateTime MainTimer_last_Tick = DateTime.Now;
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer_Calc_Remaining;
        timer_Calc_Remaining.Enabled = true;
        timer_Calc_Remaining.Interval = 100;
        timer_Calc_Remaining.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer_Calc_Remaining_Tick);
```

on main timer start or tick:

```
   timer_Main.Enabled = true;
        MainTimer_last_Tick = DateTime.Now;


 private void timer_Calc_Remaining_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int remaining_Milliseconds = (int)(MainTimer_last_Tick.AddMilliseconds(timer_Main.Interval).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
.../*
        int newValue = (timer_Main.Interval -remaining_Milliseconds) ;


        progressBar1.Maximum = timer_Main.Interval+1;

        progressBar1.Value = newValue ;*/



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an alternative timer with an interval of 1000 (milliseconds). I don't think an interval of 1ms is really an option as this will stress the system too much and is unreliable anyway.

Every time this timer elapses, you can check the number of ticks (is this always a multitude of 1000?) and subtract it from (or use modulo) 5000.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't:

That's because less than sign comes before equal sign and not the other way round

Its `<=` not `=<`

```
if (timer1.Interval <= 5000)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: In this code was different error. See answer of David Heffernan.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Interval which is a property that will not be getting changed (It will always be 5000, so checking if it is smaller than 5000 is pointless).  Also, if this code is in the `Timer1_Tick` function it will not be efficient.  However, the code I believe you need is:

```
if (timer1.Interval <= 5000)
{
  //do something
}
```

Comment: I know that Interval only property. But I didn't know what exactly I needed to check.