# Getting time until next event

Tags: c#

I have a sync timer in my app that fires up a function at a given time... now I want to know how much time is left until the next call to that function.

This is my call to the timer:

```
var syncTime = time.activitylog;
double time = TimeSpan.Parse(syncTime).TotalMilliseconds;

System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
myTimer.Interval = time;
myTimer.Start();
```

How do I get the time until next call?

Thanks

Comment: How about the timer interval you specified?

Comment: myTimer.Interval = time: time is your next call

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699517/how-do-i-check-how-much-time-remains-before-timer-fires-next-event

Comment: ?? i dont get it.. i need find some how the time that i launch the method, or the timer

Comment: However, you could have a second timer and use a System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch to track the time elapsed between the other firing and restart the stopwatch on the Tick event of the first timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another timer, and set the Interval of that the value that you want,exactly a part time of the Interval of original timer.
Then start them Simultaneously,I mean at the same time.

UPDATE :

Maybe this code describes my solution better :

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer trOriginal = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer trRemain = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        double remain = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            trOriginal.Interval = 1000;
            trRemain.Interval = 1;
            trOriginal.Tick += new EventHandler(trOriginal_Tick);
            trRemain.Tick += new EventHandler(trRemain_Tick);
            trOriginal.Start();
            trRemain.Start();
        }

        void trRemain_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            remain -= trRemain.Interval;
            Console.WriteLine("remain MS to next event : " + remain);
        }

        void trOriginal_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            remain = trOriginal.Interval;
        }
```

Comment: I think this is one way to go. I'd use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` for much more accuracy though

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to keep track of how much time has passed already and restart the `Stopwatch` with every tick of your `Timer`.

```
Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
private void DisplayTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    watch.Restart();
    // Whatever is supposed to happen, when the timer ticks
}
```

Now whenever you want to know how much time is left until the event is fired next, you can do this:

```
long timeLeft = myTimer.Interval - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```